# Automatic redirect on a select

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a `<select>` containing different page titles, a click on a title automatically redirects towards the selected page. But once the user gets there, I want the title of the page to be the selected option in the `<select>`.

So If one goes to the "books" page, once there, I want to see "books" in the `<select>`.

Is there a quick and easy way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this client side, and the values of all of your select options are absolute URLs to the "linked" page, then write something like this:

```
document.getElementById('pageSelector').value = location.href;
```

If the location isn't in the list then the previously selected (either the first option or whichever one has the `selected` attribute) will be selected.

If you want to do this server side, then as you write out all of your select options, add the `selected` attribute if the current option is for the page that you are writing out.

Answer (score 0):

So what I'm getting from your question is that your select is serving as a piece of the nav? Are you using jquery?

You could use a line of jquery at the bottom of each page saying

```
$([insert nav selector here]).val(page);
```

You'd need to define

```
var page = "the correct page";
```

on the top of each page